# Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments neuralnet package in R

Tags: r, neural-network

I have a dataset involving default information on loans, and am attempting to build a neural network to predict default. Building the neural network looks like:

```
form <- as.formula(paste("loan_status_fixed ~", paste(n[!n %in% "use"], collapse = " + ")))
```

form output is:

```
loan_status_fixed ~ addr_stateAK + addr_stateAL + addr_stateAR + 
addr_stateAZ + addr_stateCA + addr_stateCO + addr_stateCT + 
addr_stateDC + addr_stateDE + addr_stateFL + addr_stateGA + 
addr_stateHI + addr_stateIA + addr_stateID + addr_stateIL + 
addr_stateIN + addr_stateKS + addr_stateKY + addr_stateLA + 
addr_stateMA + addr_stateMD + addr_stateME + addr_stateMI + 
addr_stateMN + addr_stateMO + addr_stateNH + addr_stateNJ + 
addr_stateNM + addr_stateNV + addr_stateNY + addr_stateOH + 
addr_stateOK + addr_stateOR + addr_statePA + addr_stateRI + 
addr_stateSC + addr_stateSD + addr_stateTN + addr_stateTX + 
addr_stateUT + addr_stateVA + addr_stateVT + addr_stateWA + 
addr_stateWI + addr_stateWV + annual_inc + collections_12_mths_ex_med + 
delinq_2yrs + dti + `emp_length1 year` + `emp_length2 years` + 
`emp_length3 years` + `emp_length4 years` + `emp_length5 years` + 
`emp_length6 years` + `emp_length7 years` + `emp_length8 years` + 
`emp_length9 years` + `emp_length10+ years` + `emp_lengthn/a` + 
fico_averaged + funded_amnt + sub_gradeA1 + sub_gradeA2 + 
sub_gradeA3 + sub_gradeA4 + sub_gradeA5 + sub_gradeB1 + sub_gradeB2 + 
sub_gradeB3 + sub_gradeB4 + sub_gradeB5 + sub_gradeC1 + sub_gradeC2 + 
sub_gradeC3 + sub_gradeC4 + sub_gradeC5 + sub_gradeD1 + sub_gradeD2 + 
sub_gradeD3 + sub_gradeD4 + sub_gradeD5 + sub_gradeE1 + sub_gradeE2 + 
sub_gradeE3 + sub_gradeE4 + home_ownershipMORTGAGE + home_ownershipOWN + 
open_acc + pub_rec + purposecar + purposecredit_card + purposedebt_consolidation + 
purposeeducational + purposehome_improvement + purposehouse + 
purposemajor_purchase + purposemedical + purposemoving + 
purposeother + purposesmall_business + purposevacation + 
revol_util

    fit <- neuralnet(form, data = train,linear.output=FALSE)
```

The function works, but when I attempt to run predictions based off it:

```
    results <- neuralnet::compute(fit, test)
    Error in neurons[[i]] %*% weights[[i]] : non-conformable arguments
```

Previous questions regarding this state that this result occurs due to character or factor variables, however my data only contains numeric, integer and double data types. Other previous suggestions are that the datasets must only contain columns that are not contained within the computation, however I have corrected for this already and all columns in the train and test datasets are contained in the computation.

Below is the str of the train dataset.

```
    Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   654046 obs. of  104 variables:
 $ loan_status_fixed         : int  0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateAK              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateAL              : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateAR              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateAZ              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ addr_stateCA              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateCO              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateCT              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateDC              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateDE              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateFL              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateGA              : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateHI              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateIA              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateID              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateIL              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateIN              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateKS              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ addr_stateKY              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateLA              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateMA              : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateMD              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateME              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateMI              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateMN              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateMO              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateNH              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateNJ              : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateNM              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateNV              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateNY              : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateOH              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateOK              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateOR              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_statePA              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateRI              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateSC              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateSD              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateTN              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateTX              : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateUT              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateVA              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateVT              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateWA              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateWI              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ addr_stateWV              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ annual_inc                : num  58000 175000 66500 94800 64000 70000 95000 57000 67500 40000 ...
 $ collections_12_mths_ex_med: int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ delinq_2yrs               : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 ...
 $ dti                       : num  28.7 14.1 13.7 14.5 26.1 ...
 $ emp_length1 year          : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 ...
 $ emp_length2 years         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ emp_length3 years         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ emp_length4 years         : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ emp_length5 years         : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ emp_length6 years         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ emp_length7 years         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ emp_length8 years         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ emp_length9 years         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ emp_length10+ years       : int  1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 ...
 $ emp_lengthn/a             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ fico_averaged             : int  712 722 777 677 727 757 687 687 677 687 ...
 $ funded_amnt               : int  17000 25000 8000 20000 29425 22000 11600 16000 26575 18000 ...
 $ sub_gradeA1               : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeA2               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeA3               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeA4               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeA5               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeB1               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeB2               : int  0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeB3               : int  0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeB4               : int  1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeB5               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeC1               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeC2               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeC3               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeC4               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeC5               : int  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeD1               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 ...
 $ sub_gradeD2               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeD3               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeD4               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeD5               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeE1               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeE2               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeE3               : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ sub_gradeE4               : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ home_ownershipMORTGAGE    : int  1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 ...
 $ home_ownershipOWN         : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ open_acc                  : int  14 11 16 5 14 6 5 10 9 16 ...
 $ pub_rec                   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposecar                : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposecredit_card        : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ purposedebt_consolidation : int  1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 ...
 $ purposeeducational        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposehome_improvement   : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposehouse              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposemajor_purchase     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposemedical            : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposemoving             : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposeother              : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposesmall_business     : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ purposevacation           : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ revol_util                : num  45.1 50.1 29.7 93.4 66 0 96.5 68.2 88.4 28.6 ...
```

Comment: Instead of str() use dput(head(train)) to get an object that someone can use to help you. Does this error happen with a subset of the columns?

Comment: The `test` data must only contain the independent variables.  At first glance, you need to at least remove the dependent varible `loan_status_fixed`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that you pass a tibble to the compute() function but it requires a dataframe or matrix, as you can see from the argument definition:

> compute(x, covariate, rep = 1)
>
> Arguments
>
> covariate : a dataframe or matrix containing the variables that had
>   been used to train the neural network.

The class of a tibble always looks like what you have for `test` data:

`Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame'`.

In contrast, the class of a data frame always returns:
`data.frame`

So the solution is simple: Just cast the tibble to a dataframe before passing it:

`results <- neuralnet::compute(fit, as.data.frame(test)`